# How can I add quotes on column data when exporting Excel data to .csv?

Tags: excel, csv

I have this sample data on Excel:
[image: sample cell values]

When saving this file as .csv, I want the data look like this:

```
"ABCDEF","BFDGSFD"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Interesting question. If your data in a cell looked like `"ABCDEF"`, your .csv would have three quotes instead of one: `"""ABCDEF"""`

Comment: Have a look at this question http://superuser.com/questions/130592/how-do-you-force-excel-to-quote-all-columns-of-a-csv-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function below:

```
=CHAR(34) &A1 &CHAR(34) & ", " & CHAR(34) &B1 &CHAR(34)
```

`char(34)` is for double quote.
I think it will help you.

[image: Screenshot]